# Issue with cmake command through Bamboo

Tags: powershell, cmake, msbuild, bamboo

cmake command runs fine using powershell on the windows machine, but when I try to launch it through same m/c via bamboo agent I get following error

Failed to run MSBuild command: C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

Though this variable is there in system variable of agent. but not sure why facing this issue with bamboo

Comment: You may have to run the VS environment script first, to apply the VS environment within Bamboo. Perhaps, `vcvarsall.bat`?

Comment: this would be required once work on cmake is over. this is required to compile VS project later after cmake creates sln file

Comment: Yes, it is. But CMake tests the compiler during the configuration stage, and the environment must be setup correctly in order to do this.

Comment: I added path where vcvarsall.bat is located in Path variable in env setting, but no effect